# Unable to install edge insider(Dev ,Beta ,Canary) in hololens2 emulator

Tags: installation, microsoft-edge, hololens, hololens-emulator, chrome-canary

I want to install Edgeinsighter(Dev,Beta,Can) in my Hololens2 Emulator.

I Have downloaded Dev,Beta,Canary for hololens 2 from edgeinsighter(https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download)
and trying to install using HoloLens device portal but
Got below error

Failure reason: Windows cannot install package Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge.Canary because the package requires architecture ARM64, but this computer has architecture x64. Failure text: The deployment operation failed because the package targets the wrong processor architecture. (0x80073d10)

2.tried installing directly in HoloLens 2 emulator OS itself but got same error.

Failure reason: Windows cannot install package Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge.Canary because the package requires architecture ARM64, but this computer has architecture x64. Failure text: The deployment operation failed because the package targets the wrong processor architecture. (0x80073d10)

Can any one please help .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since the HoloLens 2 Emulator provides an architecture x64 operating system but Edge insighter requires architecture ARM64 that it is HoloLens2 device has. Currently, there is no x64 edition of Dev Edge for the HoloLens2 emulator, we only recommend using it on the device.